# ReferenceError: angular is not defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I  have create service that are interact with server side but my case error like 
angular are not defined. I am tired this error.

```
(function() {
    angular.module('myApp').factory('userService', function($http, $q, $rootScope,CONSTANTS) {
        var obj = {};
        var response = {};

       obj.setResponse = function(data) {
            response = data;
        }
        obj.getResponse = function() {
            return response;           
        obj.saveUser = function(user) {
        console.log(user);
        console.log()
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         var config = {
             headers : {
                 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
             }
         }     
         var data = angular.toJson(user);
         console.log(data);
        $http.post("user/createUser", data, config).success(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {          deferred.resolve(data);
         }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             deferred.reject();
         });
         return deferred.promise;
          }
        return obj;

        });
})();
```

Comment: `factory('userService', function($http, $q, $rootScope,CONSTANTS) `. What is `CONSTANTS`?

Comment: Seemingly obvious, but oft forgotten: did you `include` the Angular CDN? And did you do so before your script calls it?

Comment: Please don't spam the tags.

Comment: sir i have include CDN file  in my project..but then i  occur error.

Comment: Apparently this code runs before your script gets loaded.  Show us how your scripts get loaded.

Comment: constant    is used for server side functionality

Comment: my all script are lodes in my case.

Comment: share your index.html file

Comment: even if your scripts are loaded, the order in which they are loaded matters. Please share your index file (like asked above). Also please share the exact error you are getting.

Comment: When we ask for additional code, we are asking so that we can help you.  Refusing to supply us with the sought code does not help you.